# How to sign in to other websites using asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to make a website that can sign into other websites for the users, and grab certain information. For example: a web based game forum that automatically pulls your game statistics. My website would have to navigate to the game url, fill in the user name and password, sign in, then read the html once signed in (this is the easy part, for which I would simply use the HTML agility pack or something similar). Is this sign in process possible with asp.net?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Don't think of it so much as going to the page and filling stuff in. You're going to need to create a [web request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx) that contains the proper HTTP headers and data, that will look to their server to be someone that filled everything in. You'll need to look at the site you're trying to do this with for specifics, but I'd assume they're sending over a set of POST data when you click sign in. Example, pulled from MSDN and modified to be closer what you need (first few lines):

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http:/www.site.com/loginPostback");
request.Method = "POST";
// Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
string postData = "username=blah;password=blah";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);
// Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
// Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
// Get the request stream.
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
// Write the data to the request stream.
dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
// Close the Stream object.
dataStream.Close ();
// Get the response.
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
// Display the status.
Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
// Display the content.
Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
// Clean up the streams.
reader.Close ();
dataStream.Close ();
response.Close ();
```

You could then check the response stream for the HTML the server sent back after login for the information you need.

That being said, you might want to contact them and see if they have an API. If they change how their login form works you'll break. Or, if that site supports something like OAuth, go that route.

Answer (score 3):

Login processes vary from site to site. Use [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) and log in normally to the site first to see what info you need. Then  in your code use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to set the correct parameters and log in. Then mind the cookies! WebClient will return cookies. If you grab several pages make sure you set the cookies again so you are still logged in.

In rare cases HTTP authentication is used. If so just set the [Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.credentials%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in WebClient before the request is made.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID).

Comment: Curious how OpenID would help here? I would think OAuth would be what he's looking for? OpenID is for the users -- allow a common identity. OAuth is for cross-application authorization through a programming language.

Comment: For OpenID or OAuth does the other website (game website in this case) have to have the software installed? I have a few websites I need to access which wouldn't have any open standards like that installed.

Comment: Yes, the site would need to support OAuth if you were to use that, why is why you have to "fake" things out using a web request.

Answer (score 1):

Typically for things like this people use [SSO (Single Sign On)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on).

You can however perform a post injection against the site that you want to login using .Net.  It takes a little work and you will need to know where the form posts and the values that get passed.  Also you will have to add a different post injection per site that you try to login to (which will get pretty messy).

I recommend the SSO if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on how authentication is implemented on the destination website.  But when it comes right down to it, it's all HTML and HTTP [headers], so it's definitely doable.

Handling all the possible authentication schemes is going to be a nightmare though, so good luck. =)

Answer (score 0):

Why not consider some other authentication mechanism through a popular site like OpenID, Facebook, or some openly available authorization store?

Brian